# Create new Project from Dropbox Master in PhpStorm

Tags: git, dropbox, phpstorm

Can somebody tell me how to add a Git repository, that is located in my Dropbox directory, as origin/master in a PhpStorm Project?

to be more specific: I created the origin/master on a windows system and now I try to import it on a Mac OS X. But using `~/Dropbox/repositories/myproject.git` does not seem to be accepted as a repository Url, altough the test-button says otherwise.

Comment: You should not create the workspace directly within a dropbox-folder. One reason is, that PhpStorm saves files itself around (at least) every 10 seconds. This means you will have constant network activitiy.

Comment: Yes. But I want it to be the origin/master, so that I can push and pull to it. I was able to do this on windows pc but up to now I was not successful to create a new project on another (Mac) computer that uses it as origin/master.

Comment: You can clone local projects t0o. My suggestion is to create a bare (= without workspace) repository in your dropbox and on every machine clone the repository from out of your dropbox folder. Once you are done working, push it there and dropbox should start syncing. Or use a service like github, bitbucket, or such ;)

Comment: Yes, clone the repository out of my dropbox folder is what I wanted to do. Problem is, that the directory described above is not accepted, although the Test-Button, which you can use to test the repository reference, says it is ok. 

Step by step: 
1. Create project by checkout from version control
2. Use Git repository URL ~/Dropbox/gitrepositories/myproject.git
Error "Repository URL is malformed URL or non-existent repository" is shown
3. can't be so i click on "Test". Test is ok...connection successful message appears

Comment: 4. Click on Clone. Error Message "Cloning failed because repository ~/Dropbox/gitrepositories/myproject.git does not exist" But it is definitely there... ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't use GIT and haven't tested this, this sounds like a bug to me. Have you updated to the latest version (currently PhpStorm 5.0.4).

You should create  a issue in the issue tracker;
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Have you tried to use the *full* path to your Dropbox folder instead of the ~ prefix?

E.g.

```
 /Users/myshortusername/Dropbox/repositories/myproject.git
```

I suspect that the ~ confuses PhpStorm